# Need count of combinations from multiple columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have a table that has two columns - Customer_PO and Customer.
I need to know when the same po number has been used by more that one customer. Below is an example that shows PO # 111 and 11100 has been used multiple times.

[SQL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOXOA.jpg)

What I want is a query that will give me the following results based on the information above

```
111 - 2
```

What this is is a count of every combination of Customer_po and customer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you try? you can easily get this with group by statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  , Customer_PO
  , COUNT(1) AS Cnt
FROM 
  (Select distinct customer, customer_po from yourtable) a
GROUP BY Customer_PO
```

Comment: Please see edit. I didn't do a good job explain the table. Your example gives me the number 3.

Comment: @user1548989 edited the answer. I did it from phone so sorry about format and table name.